# Bitwise excluding values

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How to

```
if (x == 1) printf("2\n");
else if (x == 2) printf("1\n");
else printf("0\n");
```

using bitwise operators?

My attempt is:

```
for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    printf("%d\n",  0x03 & (0x03 ^ x));
}
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
0
3
2
1
0
```

Desired output:

```
0
2
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", x & 0xfc || !x ? 0 : 3 - x & 3);` should do the job.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think the ternary operator classifies as bitwise...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I didn't say it was bitwise. It avoids the if-else, at least.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, even for `x = 0`

Comment: @KerrekSB Along with my ninja edit, yes. ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3: Ninja what? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Ninja unicorn, I meant.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Check my answer. Not even a single logical operator. Hope you'll find it satisfactory :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an answer that needs only two operations:

```
printf("%d\n", (4 >> x) & 3);
```

Comment: Probably this was what OP is really looking for. +1.

Comment: +1: very good, although strictly speaking it's UB for `x < 0` or `x >= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: True; I assumed the question was only about the input range 0 to 7.

Answer (score 12):

This is insane, but I finally figured it out:

```
printf("%d\n", (3 & ~(x & 3)) & (0xfc >> (x << 1)));
```

Comment: @PaulR No problem. At first I thought you spotted some UB, but I just couldn't find any.

Comment: Congratulations on having spent your life on something meaningful. :-)

Comment: One final nitpick: `-` is not a bitwise operator. Bonus points if you can replace it with a bitwise equivalent.

Comment: @KerrekSB - At least he wasn't smoted by a dragon!

Comment: @PaulR Yup. Thinking about substituting it with a bitwise one.

Comment: @PaulR, H2CO3, yes, that would be great ;)

Comment: (Also, thinking about it a bit more, even `0xfc` isn't necessary. `0x18` would do the job equally well.)

Comment: Oh yes - my bad x2 - I'm going to walk away from the computer now and get a coffee...

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about the "bitwise" requirement ... If you want to compress the code, for some weird reason (the `if` version is *very easy to understand* which is a good thing), you might do something like this:

```
printf("%c\n", "210"[i == 0 ? 0 : i == 1 ? 1 : 2]);
```

This is of course almost the worst possible solution, since it's overly "clever": any reader of the code must spend valuable time to decode it, to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks unwind, thats nice, is not a requirement (just for fun)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but...

```
for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    printf("%d %d\n",  x, !x|~3&x?0:3^x);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I want to avoid ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

After several false starts, a solution with six bitwise operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < 8; ++x)
    {
        y = !(x ^ 1) << 1 | !(x ^ 2);
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that it's arguable as to whether `!` is a true bitwise operator.)

Comment: Nice. I've got a simpler formula without any logical operations at all.